# Cater for Dates greater than 2261 i.e. 9999-12-31 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have switched my data source from a CSV to a SQL query. Previously I would successfully convert all `maturity_date` to 2261 if they were greater than this year via (@jezrael):

```
df_With_NaN = pd.read_sql(strSql, pyodbc.connect(connstr))
m = df_With_NaN['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(float) > 2261
df_With_NaN['maturity_date'] = df_With_NaN['maturity_date'].mask(m, '2261' + df_With_NaN['maturity_date'].str[4:])
```

But now I get the error on this line:

```
df_With_NaN['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_With_NaN['maturity_date']) 
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00
```

Data Type:

```
maturity_date                  460862 non-null object
```

Is there additional conversion required to cater for SQL Server to Pandas?

Comment: Not sure if understand, do you need alterantive `mask` solution for `sql` ?

Comment: No I just changed the datasource fed into df_With_NaN. Ran the same code from there on and the error was raised. It appears whatever is in maturity_date is not being update by the code

Comment: I test code with `df_With_NaN  = pd.DataFrame({'maturity_date':['9999-12-31 00:00:00']})` and working nice

Comment: I'm getting NaT being returned from your test code

Comment: My code `df_With_NaN  = pd.DataFrame({'maturity_date':['9999-12-31 00:00:00']})

m = df_With_NaN['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(float) > 2261
df_With_NaN['maturity_date'] = df_With_NaN['maturity_date'].mask(m, '2261' + df_With_NaN['maturity_date'].str[4:]) 
df_With_NaN['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_With_NaN['maturity_date']) 
print (df_With_NaN)` return `2261-12-31`

Comment: Yes agree with that. Let me check from scratch

Comment: When I run against May data I'm getting the following error: 
# Error: TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

against m = df['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(float) > 2261

Comment: Idea is `m = df['maturity_date'].astype(str).str[:4].astype(float) > 2261` or `m = pd.to_numeric(df['maturity_date'].str[:4], errors='coerce') > 2261` if some not parseable dates.

Comment: Second option for m appears to have worked. Will check other datasets. Thanks @jezrael